# 高さが異なる要素をレンガ状に隙間なく並べたいのですが。ライブラリを使用せずに…

Tags: javascript, css

**高さが異なる要素を、ライブラリを使用せず、レンガ状に隙間なく並べるためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？**
・Flexboxでは無理？
・グリッドシステムでもない？
・どういうキーワードで検索すれば良い？
・どこかに基本的な考え方(実装手順)を記したチュートリアルみたいなページはないでしょうか？

---

※追記しました

---

**幅、高さ**
・指定なし
・任意(可変OK)

**順序**
・付与したい
・可能ならば左から右へ

Comment: 参考となるライブラリのソースを読んでみてはよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 幅は同じですか？ 順序は問わないのですか？

Comment: 幅は同じで高さが異なるとして、全体の幅から縦の列数を決定し列のラッパーとなるdivを作成しスタイルでfloatを指定して横並びにする。それに実際の要素を移動させて割り振る。

Comment: 高さが異なるとありますが、どの要素の高さも、「最小の要素の高さ」の倍数ですか？　それとも、高さ１と高さ１．３と高さ３．７みたいな要素が混じっていますか？

Comment: それぞれの要素の高さに関連性は全くありません。高さ自体は整数ですが、倍数にすると「1 と 1.3 と 3.7」​みたいになることはあると思います

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSSだけで2つのやり方があります。
それとご質問のレイアウトは「Masonry」という名前らしいです。

---

`flexbox`は[英語版の同じ質問にやり方](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35097136/4366452)が載ってます、選ばれた回答ではないですが。
訳しますと（ほぼコピペ）：

1. 複数列（column）を持ったflexコンテナを作る

   ```
   #flex-container {
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: column wrap;
   }
   ```
2. 要素の順序が縦になるように並び替える（3列なので3n）

   ```css
   #flex-container > :nth-child(3n + 1) { order: 1; } /* 1列目 */
   #flex-container > :nth-child(3n + 2) { order: 2; } /* 2列目 */
   #flex-container > :nth-child(3n + 3) { order: 3; } /* 3列目 */
   ```
3. 最初の列の数の分の要素の前に新規列をかならず入れる

   ```css
   #flex-container > :nth-child(-n + 3) {
     page-break-before: always; /* CSS 2.1 用 */
     break-before: always;  /* 新しい表記法 */
   }
   ```

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

#flex-container > :nth-child(3n + 1) { order: 1; } /* 1列目 */
#flex-container > :nth-child(3n + 2) { order: 2; } /* 2列目 */
#flex-container > :nth-child(3n + 3) { order: 3; } /* 3列目 */

#flex-container > :nth-child(-n + 3) {
  page-break-before: always; /* CSS 2.1 用 */
  break-before: always;  /* 新しい表記法 */
}

/* ここからは不必要 */

#flex-container > div {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 3px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 36px;
}

#flex-container > :nth-child(1) { height: 100px; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(2) { height: 50px; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(3) { height: 75px; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(4) { height: 50px; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(5) { height: 100px; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(6) { height: 50px; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(7) { height: 100px; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(8) { height: 75px; }
#flex-container > :nth-child(9) { height: 125px; }
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

---

もうひとつはCSS3の`column-count`を使う方法です。こちらも新しくベンダープリフィックスがつきますが、コンテナのスタイルに足すだけなので楽です。`flexbox`の方法と比べると順序が縦方向になるのが問題になるかもしれません。

```css
#column {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 0; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 0;
}

/* ここからは不必要 */

#column > div {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 3px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 36px;
}

#column > :nth-child(1) { height: 100px; }
#column > :nth-child(2) { height: 50px; }
#column > :nth-child(3) { height: 75px; }
#column > :nth-child(4) { height: 50px; }
#column > :nth-child(5) { height: 100px; }
#column > :nth-child(6) { height: 50px; }
#column > :nth-child(7) { height: 100px; }
#column > :nth-child(8) { height: 75px; }
#column > :nth-child(9) { height: 125px; }
```

```html
<div id="column">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

どちらも古いブラウザでは対応していないで、使う前には確認したほうがいいと思います。

Comment: 1つ目を設置してみたのですが、真横で一列に表示されてしまいます。Chromeのバージョンは53です。何か思い当たることはあるでしょうか？ 古いブラウザではないと思うのですが…

Comment: たぶん現状Chromeで`flex`に強制的にbreakを入れる方法は無いです…　Firefoxで動くのは`page-break-before`が効いてるからなのですが、実はこれは`flex`に仕様上効いてはダメらしく、そういう用途には`break-before`があるのですが、[ほとんど対応されてません](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before)（まさかのIEが対応?）。ChromeでもFirefoxみたいに動く様に実装されかけましたが、仕様にそってないので[却下された](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=473481)みたいです。Firefox以外で確認せず投稿しました、すみませんでした。

Comment: 最近ブラウザが不調だったので、もしかしたら自分だけの現象かも？ と思い質問しました。「page-break-before、break-before」の情報ありがとうございました。仕様と実装の乖離というか、ブラウザ間差異はいつまで経ってもなくならないんだな、と思いました